# Login Required Mixin acting up on a view where i didn't even include it(django)

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-autocomplete-light

So, i want my website's content only to be visible to the registered users, so i have put "LoginRequiredMixin" amd "@login_required" tags on most of my views except login and register views. Now, for registration, i want to give the registrants a choice before registering (whether they are current university students or alumni/recent graduates), this is how i am doing this:

```
class choice(View):
    template = "network/choice.html"

    def get(self, request):
        form = ChoiceForm()
        return render(request, self.template, {
            "form": form,
            "message": "Are you a curent student or an alumni/about to graduate"
        })

    def post(self, request):
        form = ChoiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            current = form.cleaned_data["current"]

        if current:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/register/current')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/register/alum')
```

where ChoiceForm just contains a boolean field, and "register/str:type" is my registration URL.

But after i submit the Choice Form:

```
<form action="{% url 'network:choice' %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form|crispy }}
          <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Proceed"
 </form>
```

the url to which i am taken to is:

```
/accounts/login/?next=/register/current
```

(i have not included any authentication check on the registration view, that won't make any sense lol)

**Where i might have gone wrong is:**

because i want anyone truing to access a restricted page to be redirected to the login page, i have defined my Urlpattern as follows:

```
path('accounts/login/', views.login_view.as_view(), name="login_view"),
path('accounts/register/<str:type>', views.register.as_view(), name="register"),
```

where 'accounts/login' is the path which django redirects to with the login_required tag. Did i do something wrong here?

[This](https://pastebin.com/KGn1dtiq) is my register view, although i am pretty sure that's not where the problem is as this view isn't even loading up even if i type in the url '`register/current`'. I am still being redirected to `accounts/login/?next=/register/current`

Urlpatterns:

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('new/<str:type>', views.new_page.as_view(), name="new"),
path('<str:type>/<str:name>', views.page.as_view(), name="page"),
path('logout', views.logout_view, name="logout_view"),
path('accounts/login/', views.login_view.as_view(), name="login_view"),
path('accounts/register/<str:type>', views.register.as_view(), name="register"),
path('choice', views.choice.as_view(), name="choice"),
```

Comment: Show your `register` view and also show your other url patterns.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have given a link to my register view and also all my url patterns, kindly have a look

Comment: What is happening is that `register/<str:type>` is matched by `<str:type>/<str:name>` (`register` can be a type and the other parameter can be a name yes?) and hence instead of your view `register` the view `page` is being used. Either order your urls better or design them to be more descriptive.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat oh got it, thank you very much